# how to run python script from trigger mysql in ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

I tried to use sys_exec but this feature doesn't work in Ubuntu. Maybe somebody knows how to run the script on event in Mysql(in windows works but not in linux)

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER On_New_Email_Insert
AFTER INSERT ON emails
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(250);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd = CONCAT('python3 checker.py ',NEW.customer_id);
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" in more technical terms, like specific error messages?

Comment: `sys_exec()` is not a MySQL built-in function. It's a UDF you have to install.

Comment: I know sys_exec() is not system functiion,. i compiled from git and try to call this and recieve message "Wrong symbol"